# Using CSS transitions to reveal more digits in a number

Tags: css, css-transitions

In HTML we have a number like `12.34` When someone hovers their mouse over it I'd like it to expand with some sort of transition to reveal additional significant digits, for example `12.345678`.

Is this possible with just CSS and what would be the simplest way? (e.g. I probably don't want to use a fixed width div with overflow hidden, which then expands, because the width could be variable with numbers like `123.45`, `1,234.56` etc.)  So I'm thinking have two divs one rounded, one with all digits - but then we'd need some way to transition between them smoothly.  Thanks!

Comment: css deals only with presentation/formatting.. if you want to dynamically change a string, then you'll need javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Marc B - there are too many possible variations to determine the dot position to use just one field without resorting to using JS. However this is my solution, with two fields

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisdanek/mSjsj/1/

```
<span class="num">
    <span class="abbr">123.45</span>
    <span class="full">123.4567</span>
</span>

<span class="num">
    <span class="abbr">123,345,567.45</span>
    <span class="full">123,345,567.45000</span>
</span>

<span class="num">
    <span class="abbr">123,345,567.455634434</span>
    <span class="full">short one</span>
</span><!-- this one is not possible with numbers, but just to show how it works with shorter second number -->
```

And CSS

```
.num { 
    position: relative; 
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid red; 
    -webkit-transition: width 0.2s; 
    -moz-transition: width 0.2s; 
    -o-transition: width 0.2s; 
    transition: width 0.2s;    
}
.abbr { 
    position: relative; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1; 
    z-index: 1; 
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s; 
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s; 
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s; 
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
.full { 
    top: 5px; left: 5px; 
    position: absolute; 
    display: block;
    z-index: 0; 
    opacity: 0; 
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s; 
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s; 
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s; 
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    color: red;
}
.num:hover .abbr { position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 5px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
.num:hover .full { position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; opacity: 1; z-index: 1; }
```

The best I could come up with is opacity change, as it doesn’t require setting width on the container. Without that it’s impossible to make a transition for width (you’ll notice transition code is added, but it’s not being executed). Perhaps someone else can come up with a workaround.

Comment: Very clever, swapping `position:relative` and `position:absolute`! It took a while to understand what was happening :) Animating the implicit width doesn't appear to have any effect though.

Comment: Yes, width won't animate unless it's set to something different than `auto`. I’ll post a solution if I think of one, but right now I am afraid there isn’t one that would allow making the width animate as well. (check my comment from the answer under the posted code)

Comment: Pretty clever, and impressive solution without JS. Thanks Chris!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the opacity transitions to work cleanly on our side for some reason.  But this is a much simpler version in case it helps someone: (in SASS)

```
.num {
  display: inline-block;
  .abbr { display: block; }
  .full { display: none; }

  &:hover {
    .abbr { display: none; }
    .full { display: block; }
  }
}
```